# Toggle Button With Text Below

Tags: android

How to make a toggle button with text below?
What I want is 
[image: Toggle button]

This is my current code

```
<ToggleButton
 android:id="@+id/button_check_in"
 android:layout_width="40dp"
 android:layout_height="40dp"
 android:background="@drawable/button_check_in"
 android:checked="false"
 android:text=""
 android:textOff=""
 android:textOn=""
 android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
 />

<--button_check_in.xml-->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tick_blue"
      android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_tick_black"
      android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/button_check_in"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:checked="false"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/button_check_in"
    android:text=""
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textOff="Follow"
    android:textOn="Followed" />
```

Comment: @Rick I have tested and working fine. Let me know the issue that you are facing.

Comment: Oh, i retry this code again. It seems working now.. Thanks so much!!! Voted this as answer!!

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/button_check_in"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Like"enter code here
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center|start"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how to click the toggle button along with the textview together? If I do this, I just can click the toggle button but the textview is not clicked

Comment: I think u want to change the text when u click the toogle button......For that give id for the textView, so that if u make a click in toogle button change the text in the textView.

Comment: if u think my answer is useful, please tick as useful...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work with toggle button.

You have to work with the Imageviews by implemnting boolean flags for each clicks.

If you are looking for a Menu/Navigation Please look into it [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html)

hope this helps